# How to find package for a dictionary object in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, abap, abap-adt

I am trying to determine a package for an data element, or domain, or whatever via Eclipse ADT, but have no luck. I'm doing usual object search via project search (Ctrl-Shift-A), and both Global search (Ctrl-H), the result is the same.

I see domain properties window

[image]

and it has no clue about what package it is.

What I've tried so far:

1. Using filters in project search bar, callable via Ctrl-Space

[image]

Package filter does not help, it lists **all** packages, not the relevant ones, where this domain was found. Picking each and every package will take infinity amount of time, because the hierarchy is huge.

2. Pressing "Link with editor" button

[image]

For some reason it doesn't work, should it with DDIC objects? When I press it with domain opened right-side, just nothing happens. In the help and e.g. [here](https://software-heroes.com/en/blog/abap-tools-work-with-eclipse-search) they describe it should open the object in the left within hierarchy.

Is it something broken with my ADT or this button doesn't work with DDIC objects?

P.S. It is ABAP Cloud trial system, if that matters.

Comment: The "Link with editor Button" works for me.

Comment: @GertArnold done yet yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/tags/abap-adt/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package can be seen in Properties tool (see the bottom part of the screenshot below)
[image]

Comment: thanks, it shows. and even hierarchy is immediately unfolded at the place of this domain. However for MATNR domain it does not unfolded in ABAP Cloud, and MATNR domain is hidden in hierarchy for some reason. This seems to be the cause